# Insufficient privileges to drop schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Trying to grant a role access to drop a schema from a database in Snowflake.  What grants do I need to apply?

Currently if we try to execute this statement for the user:
`DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS 'schemaname_123'`

We get this error:
`SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'schemaname_123'`

The role currently has these grants on the database
`GRANT USAGE, MONITOR, CREATE SCHEMA ON DATABASE RAW TO ROLE INGESTION_ROLE;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DROP privilege is tied to the object owner.

To drop a schema, you must be using a role that has ownership privilege on the schema.

Note that granting ownership in fact transfer the ownership to another role.

```
grant ownership on schema schemaname_123 to role INGESTION_ROLE;
```

Comment: To expand on "you must be using a role that has ownership privilege on the schema": You can also use a role which is a member of the role who has ownership of the table (a role higher in the hierarchy)

Comment: Because the role already had CREATE TABLE grants, the change ownershup raised an error until I added "revoke current grants" to the end of the statement:
grant ownership on schema schemaname_123 to role INGESTION_ROLE revoke current grants